# How to execute raw SQL query in OpenSearch .Net Client

Tags: opensearch, amazon-opensearch

I know that we can write DSL queries to search OpenSearch. But for some reason, I need to execute some raw SQL queries to get the result using the dotNet client. I can execute the raw query on DevTool in the OpenSearch Dashboard but I need to execute this from the .Net Client.

```
POST _plugins/_sql
{
  "query":"""SELECT * FROM bookmark_questions WHERE studentId = 5"""
}
```

[Note: This is just a sample query.]

In ElasticSearch, it's possible. [Link](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/issues/4000).

```
var q = new QuerySqlRequest()
{
   Query = req,
   Format = "json"
};
var resp = await _elasticClient.Sql.QueryAsync(q);
```

But in Opensearch, I couldn't do that.
**How can I execute this type of query?**

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use the [low level OpenSearch client](https://opensearch.org/docs/latest/clients/OpenSearch-dot-net/) to do this, so you can construct the query yourself rather than depending on methods implemented for the high level client.